# Cannot call method createDocumentFragment of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to implement [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

I am having following link `<a class="simple-ajax-popup" href="/index.json">load json</a>`

When I click the link, lightbox is in loading state and throws an exception as

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

I am using rails 4 and also I have `jquery-fileupload` plugin but it is working.

Comment: which version of magnific you are using ?

Comment: what is in index.json

Answer (score 2):

Please, read this [Documentation: content type](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types)

You could not use json as html. You should wrap json to html.
What You could do?

Something like this:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '<div class="white-popup">Dynamically created popup</div>', // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
    type: 'inline'
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {
       $.getJSON("/index.json").done(function( data) {
             data.each( function(index, value) {
               $("div.white-popup").append(value);
                       });
              })
       },
      close: function() {
           // Will fire when popup is closed
       }
});
```

I hope it help.